# Deixar app somente em modo retrato

Tags: android

Como fazer com que a aplicação funcione somente em modo retrato, e ao virar a tela nada aconteça ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723823/i-want-my-android-application-to-be-only-run-in-portrait-mode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basta adicionar no seu AndroidManifest.XML `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Além da forma como o Leofontes demostrou definindo o atributo `android:screenOrientation` como `portrait` na sua `<activity>` localizado no `AndroidManifest.xml`, você pode também inserir programaticamente usando o método [setRequestedOrientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)). Veja um exemplo:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Então ficaria desta forma seu `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

<sup>**Nota**: Um tempo atrás o Google lançou uma nota que aplicações que funcionam somente em um modo, sendo *portrait* ou *landscape*, seriam menos visíveis para download (quando eu encontrar a noticia eu deixo o *link* aqui). Então é importante, você pensar nessas questões, de criar *layouts* que suportam as duas orientações simultaneamente.</sup>