# Manter foco do item BottomNavigationView clicado após rotacionar tela

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estou com um problema quando rotaciono a tela.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

- Uma HomeActivity que trata os clicks na BottomNavigationView (são 4 itens)
- Cada item da BottomNavigationView carrega um Fragment com dados distintos

Porém, quando eu rotaciono a tela em qualquer um deles (item), o Fragment perde foco e é exibido para o usuário o Fragment da posição 0 (o primeiro). O que quero é: manter a Fragment selecionada quando o usuário rotacionar a tela em qualquer uma delas.

Como posso resolver isso? 
Dei uma olhada no Ciclo de Vida dos Fragments, mas não consigo compreender como posso resolver.

**onCreate da HomeActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/futura.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, AgendaFragment.newInstance());
    transaction.commit();

    mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_bottom);

    mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_agenda:
                    selectedFragment = AgendaFragment.newInstance();
                    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.txt_nossa_agenda));
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_palestras:
                    selectedFragment = PalestrasFragment.newInstance();
                    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.txt_nossas_palestras));
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_minicursos:
                    selectedFragment = MinicursosFragment.newInstance();
                    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.txt_nossos_minicursos));
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_workshops:
                    selectedFragment = WorkshopsFragment.newInstance();
                    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.txt_nossos_workshops));
                    break;
            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

**onCreate/onCreateView da Fragment que perde o foco (Ex: PalestranteFragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palestras, container, false);

    mArrayListPalestrantes = new ArrayList<>();
    mRecyclerViewPalestrantes = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_palestras);
    mRecyclerViewPalestrantes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    carregaLista();

    PalestranteAdapter adapter = new PalestranteAdapter(mArrayListPalestrantes);
    mRecyclerViewPalestrantes.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

**onCreate/onCreateView da Fragment que é apresentada quando rotaciona tela**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agenda, container, false);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.result_tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    String weekDay;
    SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.US);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    weekDay = dayFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    Log.i("dia", "Hoje é: " + weekDay);

    switch (weekDay){
        case "Monday":
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            break;
        case "Tuesday":
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            break;
        case "Wednesday":
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            break;
        case "Thursday":
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
            break;
        case "Friday":
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
            break;
        case "Saturday":
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            break;
        case "Sunday":
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            break;
        default:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    return view;
}
```

**Imagens**
*Esquerda: Fragment selecionada -*
*Direita: Fragment principal é mostrada e a Fragment selecionada perde foco*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem duas opções, ou bloqueia a tela quando rotacionar ou você salva o estado. Veja essa resposta pra bloquear: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193429/deixar-app-somente-em-modo-retrato/193475#193475 Veja essa resposta de como pode ser feito para salvar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168412/35406

Answer (score 1):

Tente primeiro salvar o id do BottomNavigationView selecionado no `onSaveInstanceState()` em sua HomeActivity

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Salva o id do menu do fragment selecionado
    int idMenu = bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.item_id);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("idMenu", idMenu);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

E depois recuperar no `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Chama a superclass primeiro

// Verifica se está criando uma instância previamente destruída
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // Restaura o id do menu e o seleciona
   int idMenu = savedInstanceState.getInt("idMenu");
   bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(idMenu);

} else {
    // Caso seja uma nova instância, inicializa normalmente
}
}
```

Mais informações sobre o [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).

Answer (score 0):

Todas as vezes que a tela do celular é girada sua Activity é destruída e depois reiniciada. Se quiser que os dados não sejam perdidos durante esta rotação você precisará salvá-los usando os métodos ciclos de vida.

Sugestão: Salve os dados que precisa guardar no onDestroy() e recupere-os no onCreate() e adapte a view para se montar de acordo com os dados recuperados.

Veja sobre [Salvando estados persistentemente](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState)